# Boot repair showing error

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

Ubuntu 16.04 is showing grub terminal on startup.Tried boot repair too but it gives me the following URL for troubleshooting in case the problem persists (which it does): http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bzDsbJWRxb/

I would like some help going through the above URL and troubleshooting to solve the problem of not being able to boot into ubuntu.

Comment: What brand/model system? Or motherboard? Can you boot ubuntu entry directly from UEFI boot menu? You show both signed & unsigned kernels. Only the signed kernel should work with UEFI Secure boot on.

Comment: It looks like Boot-Repair is confused by the *multiple* Ubuntu installations on the computer in question and at least one of them being seriously broken. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify why you have two Ubuntu installations and whether you intend to keep them both? Thanks.

Comment: now i have removed the new ubuntu , old ubuntu is need to be fixed please help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have secure boot enabled on your computer, try to disable that and rerun the boot repair.